# What's new in SharePoint 2016 online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

I have found a few documents about new features in SharePoint 2016 on premise, but I can't find anything about SharePoint 2016 online version. Especially I am interested in BI part. Do you know any resources about this or about do you know Microsoft plans according SharPoint online new release?

Comment: If it's made it to On Prem, it's likely already been in SPO.  SPO gets updates before On Prem.  Microsoft rolls these features out as they're ready, so it's difficult to find a list of what the features are.  You can find updates on their [blog](https://blogs.office.com).  You can filter the articles using the tools at the top.  [Here](https://blogs.office.com/2016/02/02/share-your-excel-insights-with-power-bi/) is a recent article on Power BI for Excel.

Comment: SharePoint Online brings in a lot of new features of which the ability for a hybrid deployment is a great thing. Not only that, looks like it has lot many features. I found an interesting article [here](http://www.hubfly.com/blog/the-basics/new-features-in-sharepoint-2016/) for a quick read.

Comment: SharePoint 2016 brings lots of new features and enhancements. Please refer below link for detailed information for SharePoint 2016 features - http://sidteche.blogspot.in/2017/08/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Hi @Sid, First thank you for your contribution, Second, we are searching for a detailed answer and adding the link as Ref, Third, the OP asks for the new features for SharePoint Online not on-prem, so your answer will be flagged as not as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wjervis mention, features that are new in SharePoint 2016 On premise has been and are being deployed and you might be using them right now.

However, Microsoft pushes out new features to servers, not tenants so there is no guarantee that you have access to anything new yet. And there is always a chance that features that will make it to on premise won't be available to O365 and the other way around.

The best place for what new features that are being implemented in Office 365 is found on their roadmap.

[Office 365 Roadmap](http://fasttrack.office.com/roadmap)